# oledb insert into syntax error

Tags: asp.net, oledb

In the execution of this code, I get this error: `Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.`

Here is my code:

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Users " & _
                   " (PKID, Username, Password, Email, PasswordQuestion, " & _
                   " PasswordAnswer, IsApproved," & _
                   " Comment, CreationDate, LastPasswordChangedDate, LastActivityDate," & _
                   " ApplicationName, IsLockedOut, LastLockedOutDate," & _
                   " FailedPasswordAttemptCount, FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart, " & _
                   " FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart)" & _
                   " Values (@PKID, @Username, @Password, @Email, @PasswordQuestion, @PasswordAnswer, @IsApproved, @Comment, @CreationDate, @LastPasswordChangedDate, @LastActivityDate, @ApplicationName, @IsLockedOut, @LastLockedOutDate, @FailedPasswordAttemptCount, @FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart, @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount, @FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart)", conn)

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PKID", OleDbType.Guid).Value = providerUserKey
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = username
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = EncodePassword(password)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", OleDbType.VarChar, 128).Value = email
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PasswordQuestion", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = passwordQuestion
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@PasswordAnswer", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = EncodePassword(passwordAnswer)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IsApproved", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = isApproved
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Comment", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = ""
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@CreationDate", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = createDate
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastPasswordChangedDate", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = createDate
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastActivityDate", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = createDate
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ApplicationName", OleDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = pApplicationName
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@IsLockedOut", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = False
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastLockedOutDate", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = createDate
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FailedPasswordAttemptCount", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 0
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FailedPasswordAttemptWindowStart", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = createDate
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptCount", OleDbType.Integer).Value = 0
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FailedPasswordAnswerAttemptWindowStart", OleDbType.DBTimeStamp).Value = createDate
```

Can someone explain the problem in my code?

Answer (score 0):

try by changing `OleDbCommand` text

```
   " Values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", conn)
```

instead of named parameters

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
>   parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
>   OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
>   question mark (?) placeholder must be used.

Comment: I try to change my code in: cmd.CommandText and add the ? ?, but the error remains. the "createDate" is DateTime.Now.. is it right?

Comment: is there any inner exception?

Comment: No, the error is given on this line: Dim recAdded As Integer = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()